# Process long arrays in Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

I'am developing an application that makes users able to broadcast videos. As many social network do, users need to receive a notification when someone goes live. To do so I'am using `Cloud Functions` and i pass to the functions the array of the users that must receive the notification; for every user of the array I need to extract the `FCM TOKEN` from the server and then send the notification.

For arrays of 10 / 20 Users the functions doesn't take so long, but for 150/300 users sometimes I get timeout or a very slow execution.

So my question is: Is it possible to divide the array in groups of 20/30 users and process many arrays at same time??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 way to answer this

- From a development point of view, some languages are easier for allowing the concurrent processing (Go is very handy for this). So, like this, because you spend a lot of time in API call (FCM), it's a first solution to perform several calls concurrently
- From an architecture point of view, PubSub and/or Cloud Task are well designed for this

  - Your first function only creates chunk of message to send and posts them to Cloud Task or PubSub
  - Your second function receives the chunks and sends the messages. The chunks are processed in parallel on several functions.